# Error reading path in java

Tags: java, string, file-io, bufferedreader, filereader

I am trying to read a text file in java, but I am having this annoying FILENOTFOUND EXCEPTION:

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("/home/asad/workspace/MyFirstProject/HelloWorld.txt"));
    while ((reader = br.readLine())!= null);
    System.out.print(reader);
    br.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the simplest code and should read a text file name HelloWorld from the specified path, should store it in the string "reader" and displays its output on the console, but the compiler is having problems locating the file.

Strange thing is, I have tried looking for the file path using getCanonicalPath() and it is specifying to the same path I have been looking, but the compiler is not finding the file. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure about *HelloWorld.txt* ? isn't it *HelloWorld.java* ?

Comment: Check the file permissions and also check what does the `exists()` method returns. If the file is there and you still get a FileNotFound, these are the ones the come up first.

Comment: The content of a file is totally independent of the extension. What is the exact name of the file ? *HelloWorld.txt* or *HelloWorld.java* ?

Comment: @prabugp, there aren't any permission exceptions thrown, but can you please tell me where to use the exists()?

Comment: @Asad, `File file = new File(mypath + myfile); System.out.println("Does file exist? " + file.exists());`

Comment: @ ortis yes, its HelloWorld.txt

Comment: I assume you are under Linux. Try `cat /home/asad/workspace/MyFirstProject/HelloWorld.txt`. Whats the output ?

Comment: If you go to command line and enter: 
`cat /home/asad/workspace/MyFirstProject/HelloWorld.txt` does it print the content for you? What OS are you on BTW?

Comment: @munyal it is returning false, that's kind of strange now

Comment: @ ortis and espinosa

it is kind of embarrassing now for me, but if i directly enter all the path in the terminal it doesn't locate the file, but my going one by one through cd and entering cat HelloWorld inside the MyFirstProject directory prints the contents of the file

Comment: It's probably an issue about Linux and not java. May be some slink or remote mount issue. You should ask on Unix SO.

Comment: Also `while ((reader = br.readLine())!= null);` is not correct, the `reader` will contain only the value, which in this case is `null`, this is probably not what you want. You need some aggregation in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the while-loop the empty statement `;` was executed till the end of file.

```
if ((reader = br.readLine())!= null) { // Not ;
    System.out.println(reader); // Not print, as reader has "\r\n" removed
}
br.close();
```

Using `if` instead of the usual `while` to retrieve the first line only.

The FileNotFoundException is probably true. To find the typo you can do in a terminal:

```
cat /home/asad/workspace/MyFirstProject/HelloWorld.txt
ls /home/asad/workspace/MyFirstProject
ls /home/asad/workspace
```

Most likely it should have been "MyfirstProject" or so.

Comment: Nice spotting ! Although this would not fix the `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: @joop i have put that semicolon without parenthesis because the text file contains only a single file.

Comment: Then you could get rid if the `while` statement and just use `reader = br.readLine();`

Comment: If the file contains just one line, change the `while` into an `if`. Keep the braces, otherwise you will print null. Just saw another detail.

Comment: @ortis right; I was overeager, and the "error" is no bug of course.

Comment: The `while ((reader = br.readLine())!= null);` would cause `reader` to contain only the last value, which in this case is `null`, so not even a line would be printed.

Comment: @Espinosa yes, I changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this test before your code:

```
File file = new File("/home/asad/workspace/MyFirstProject/HelloWorld.txt");
if( file.exists() ) {
    System.out.println("File exists!");
} else {
    System.out.println("File not existst!");
}
```

if you get FileNotFoundException, file isn't in this localization or file name is incorrect.

Comment: i have done that already and it is returning false, but it shows the file in the same directory if i see it through terminal.

Comment: show output from command 'ls -l /home/asad/workspace/MyFirstProject/HelloWorld.txt'

Comment: thanks kris, but the problem was resolved by excluding the type.

Answer (score 0):

i just spotted the problem of my code, 
by omitting the .txt from the path printed the solution.

i changed the code from

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("/home/asad/workspace/MyFirstProject/HelloWorld.txt"));
```

to

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("/home/asad/workspace/MyFirstProject/HelloWorld"));
```

and boosh the console printed the text stored in the file.